# Thymeleaf: How to use boolean operator in JavaScript using Thymeleaf

Tags: java, javascript, exception, thymeleaf

I am using thymeleaf, in javascript using `th:inline="javascript"`, but when we add Boolean conditions in java script thymeleaf thow an exception as below:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 14; columnNumber: 22; The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:441)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1436)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEntityReference(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1845)
.............................
```

Below is my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.fancybox').fancybox({
            'width' :'623px',
            'maxHeight':'156px'
        });

        var catId = $("#category").val();
        if(catId != null && catId != ''){
            findSubCategories();
            /*<![CDATA[*/
                var subCatId = /*[[${searchProductDto.subCategory}]]*/
            /*]]>*/
            debugger;
            if(subCatId != null){
                $("#subCategory").val(subCatId);
            }
        }
    });
...............................
```

how we use & operator in thymeleaf?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

wrap the if block with `<![CDATA[` block

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
var a =b = true;
/*<![CDATA[*/
if(a && b){
    alert('Yea');
}/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Comment: how we use `&amp;` in if condition, browser throw an error.

Comment: @HarmeetSinghTaara: Updated my ans..let me know if you still have issue

Comment: Correct, yet there is IMHO no reason for wrapping only selected blocks into the CDATA section. Simply always wrap the whole JS code. Also note, that treating special characters like `&` correctly (here, with the help of CDATA) is purely XML thing, you need to do that no matter if you use Thymeleaf, or another XML-based tool.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `<!CDATA[` protection around the entire contents of the `script` tag.

Comment: @HarmeetSinghTaara Not in the code you posted; you only used CDATA around the inlined variable.