# Thymeleaf:SAXParseException ocurrs during executing for loop in javascript block

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

On thymeleaf html temlate I try to execute simple for loop in js

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
var data = [[${dataGraph}]];
for(var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++){
  * * *
  some code
  * * * 
}
</script>
```

When I start the app and go to this template server returns

```
[THYMELEAF][http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-8] Fatal error during parsing org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: 
The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
Exception processing template "admin/home": Exception parsing document: template="admin/home", line 206 - column 23
```

line 206 column 23 - it's a for loop which I've written above.

What's wrong with this for loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Thymeleaf: How to use boolean operator in JavaScript using Thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28718421/thymeleaf-how-to-use-boolean-operator-in-javascript-using-thymeleaf)

Comment: yees, it works, thanks!

Comment: I missed the /*<![CDATA[*/       [some code]              /*<![CDATA[*/